# From the depth of xml in php->mysql Nodes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml

I have an XML file.

I want to add data from it to MySQL, but I have problems.

The data that I want to add is very deep, in the `"offers"` tab.

The required additional objects are written as `"<offer ......>"`.

There are many parameters, such as `(name model picture price url ....)`.

I can not get them at all, the maximum I could get is `"name"` from `"<shop>"`.

How can I find "Music center"?

```html
<?php
echo 'ver 3000';
$url = "http://myurlwebsite.com/333.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
$data2 = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo ' [NEW STRING] ';
//$easy = stristr($data2, '<delivery-options');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data2);

foreach ($xml -> offer as $row) {
         echo '+';
 $name = $row -> name; 
 echo $name;       
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `<offer>` information, then you need to specify the path from the base of the document to the data your after.  Note that in SimpleXML, the root element `<yml_catalog>` is `$xml` in your case.

```
foreach ($xml->shop->offers->offer as $row) {
    echo '+';
    $name = $row -> name;
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an actual copy of the XML data to your question rather than an image so I can test it.

Comment: I've changed the code but couldn't get it to load the data from the CURL code, this is where you will need to make sure that this data is actually correct before calling `simplexml_load_string()`.

Comment: Yes, it work. I thought that the problem was that long name <offer available="true" bid="10" cbid="10" id="10005360" type="vendor.model">, thought would work only with <offer> </ offer>. Thank you so much, Спасибо!